# How to find a surjective but not injective function from a set $M$ to itself

Tags: functions, relations

When $M := \{1,2,3\}$ and $f: M \to M$ I have to find $f(1), f(2), f(3)$ such that $f$ is surjective but not bijective.

I don't get it how this is possible as every element the domain $(M)$ should point to at least one of the codomain.

$f(1,2,3) = (3,2,1)$ would be surjective but injective right?

$f(1,2,3) = (1,1,2)$ is not injective but then not surjective.
What am I missing to solve this right?

Just to get this right: When I have $f(1,2,3) = (3,1,2)$ is it right to assume that the inverse of f would be $f(1,2,3) = (2,3,1)$?

Comment: Since $M$ is a finite set, any function from $M$ to $M$ is injective if and only if it is surjective.

Comment: So the question is a bait and there can't any function thats surjective but not injective? How about the inverse, am I right about that?

Comment: Are you sure $f$ must be a function?

Comment: A set $M$ is finite if and only if every injection $M\to M$ is surjective. A set $M$ is finite if and only if every surjection $M\to M$ is injective.

Comment: Yes f must be a function

Comment: How is a function on itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For finite sets $M$ there holds that a function $f:M\to M$ is *injective* if and only if it is *surjective*. Hence you cannot find such a function you are looking for.